# Light issue while exporting as gltf/glb

Tags: modeling, gltf

I have made a 3D model in blender that will be used in an web application made using three.js. I have added area lights, point lights and objects with emission inside the model to light it up but when I export it and use it in three.js the scene is completely black. After researching online, I got to know to that I can bake lights into the texture. I tried this solution but it didn't help. While exporting, I also tried ticking the punctual light checkbox but got the same result. The walls and windows seen in the model as made using Archimesh. Stairs and the first floor is made by me. The defaults textures given by archimesh are also changed. Can anyone suggest me what I can do to resolve this issue.

model as seen in blender
[image]

model as seen in web app
[image]

model without the main area light
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can only understand your query partially, and it is missing lots of background and your code as well to help you better but from what I can understand,
You want to

- import area & other lights from blender model to three.js
- You want your material to have emission set to it.

Actions I recommend you to do to fix the issue

- Though it is stated that three.js does support area lights, you cannot import it casually by just adding it into blender, it is added into the model using `THREE.RectAreaLight`.
- Point Lights are a different story though. You can import them but the scale that Three.js uses is different from Blender. Meaning value = 1 in blender is 10 or 100 in Three.js
- For emission, you will need to keep your model as simple as possible for material choice and look up Three.js Examples of how material are added to objects.
- Very Important to check out this website https://threejs.org/editor/
- Lastly checkout my github page at https://dharnil-dev.github.io/dharnil-portfolio/ . You will see a Three.js Portfolio/Playground.

Please do update your question with more details.